# error when working with knockoutJS visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I work with knockoutJS and I have an error when I want close a block `div` or `h` html tag.
My Javascript code where the error occurs:

```
function myModel(){
this.flags = false;
    this.getFlag = ko.computed(function(){
        if(this.flags == false){
            this.flags = true;
        }else{
            this.flags = false;
        }
        console.log(this.flags);
        return this.flags;
    });
}
ko.applyBindings(new myModel());
```

My HTML:

```
<button data-bind="click: getFlag">Click button</button>
<h3 data-bind="visible: getFlag()">test visible</h3>
```

When I click my button I have this message in the browser console:

> false Uncaught Error: Cannot write a value to a ko.computed unless you
>   specify a 'write' option. If you wish to read the current value, don't
>   pass any parameters.knockout-3.3.0.js:44 gknockout-3.3.0.js:83
>   (anonymous function)

When I write my javascript code without function `ko.computed()`

```
    this.flags = false;
    this.getFlag = function(){
        if(this.flags == false){
            this.flags = true;
        }else{
            this.flags = false;
        }
        console.log(this.flags);   
        return this.flags;
    };
```

I have this message in browser console:

true

When I press the button I have `false`, and etc `true` `false` `true` `false` but `visible` doesn't work.
What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first you need to declare your properties as observable:

```
var self = this;
self.flag = ko.observable(false);
```

Next we'll make a toggle to switch the flag back and forth:

```
self.toggleFlag = function(){
   self.flag(!self.flag());
}
```

Now you can bind:

```
<button data-bind="click: toggleFlag">Click button</button>
<h3 data-bind="visible: flag">test visible</h3>
```

Comment: this code don't work in me, in result i have in console true false true false

Comment: flags variable in function getFlag() changes his value, but global change flags does not change his value

Comment: Ok, I missed a couple things in your post.  Updated my answer.